# CMake build & link to library without installing to /usr/local or elsewhere

Tags: cmake

I'm trying to include an external library in a build environment that uses CMake.  I'm not trying to install it on the local system (in fact I'd rather *not* do that, I don't want `/usr/local` clogged up with all kinds of libraries); I'd just like to have the resulting `libxml2.a` available for linking with my executable.  I can build it fine with the following in CMakeLists.txt:

```
set (LIBXML_PATH ${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/libxml2-2.9.1)
add_custom_target (build_libxml ALL
    COMMENT "Building libxml"
    COMMAND ./configure --prefix=/tmp
    COMMAND make
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIBXML_PATH}
)
```

But I'm still having trouble with the following:

1)  Is this the right approach in the first place, for the general purpose of getting libraries built with `configure` and `make` into a CMake environment?

2)  How do I get the resulting library (i.e. `libxml2.a`) under my `build` output directory?

3)  How can I link to that library for my executable builds?

I tried a fiddly solution with

```
ADD_LIBRARY( xml2 STATIC libxml2.a )
```

but it seems like there must be a better way than hauling a whole library's contents into… a library.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make it clearer to CMake what is going on here.  All it can see now is that you have some custom command that it will run every time.  Instead of using `add_custom_target` with `COMMAND`, I've found it better to use `add_custom_command`.

Something like this:

```
set (LIBXML_PATH ${MY_SOURCE_DIR}/libxml2-2.9.1)
add_custom_command(
    OUTPUT libxml2.a
    COMMENT "Building libxml"
    COMMAND ./configure --prefix=/tmp
    COMMAND make
    WORKING_DIRECTORY ${LIBXML_PATH}
)
target_link_libraries(your-program libxml2.a)
```

By doing it this way, CMake can understand that your custom command's essential product is `libxml2.a`, and when CMake sees something depending on that, it will run the command (if the library doesn't exist already).

Comment: Thanks.  I couldn't quite get it to fit in with what I'm working on, and I'm trying a wholly different approach now so I can't test this out as "the answer."  Up-vote for appreciation, though.